# can Unity dashboard search the phrase approximately?

Tags: unity

I want to know is there an option that unity dashboard search the phrase in not an exact manner, for example when you want open "firefox", if you type "friefox" or "frefox" it would not find the application, but in fast typing this happens a lot. so i think it would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Unity uses keywords in the .desktop file of an application to match the application, so "firefox" and "browser" would work.

It currently does not do mispellings or anything like that, that would be a nice feature to file a bug on though:

- [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)